# How to make a background image "shine through" the letters of a text

Tags: html, css, background-image

Okay.  My title probably did not give you a good enough idea of what my problem actually is, but I don't really know how to sum up this particular problem in a title.
Here is my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ranga');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+Mono+One');
body {
  background: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/X5iq6dZ.jpg");
}

header {
  background: url(https://raw.github.com/mmoustafa/Chalkboard/master/img/bg.png);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: 'Londrina Sketch', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

header nav {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 80%;
}

header nav a {
  font-family: 'Ranga', cursive;
  text-decoration: overline;
  margin-right: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

header nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}

#section1 span {
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Nathaniel Santley | Welcome to my site!</title>
  <link href="NathanielSantley.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Hi!  My name is Nathaniel Santley.  I'm a programming enthusiast, video game lover, and a nerd down to the core.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="nathaniel, santley, Nathaniel, Santley, programming, video, games">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathaniel Santley">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Nathaniel Santley</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="section1">
    <span><h1>NATHANIEL SANTLEY</h1><br /><h2>Programming enthusiast.<br />Video game lover.<br />Nerd down to the core.</h2></span>
  </section>
  <section>

  </section>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>
```

I want the `#section1 span` to have the background of white and I want the image to go through the `h1` and `h2` (not the white background), but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: A little confused by what you're looking for; do you want a white background only where there isn't text, and in the areas with text you'll be able to see the background image? Or perhaps vice-versa?

Comment: I want it to be like if you cut out text shapes on paper and then put the cut paper on my background image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution for you. Changes are only in the last two CSS rules:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Sketch');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ranga');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik+Mono+One');
body {
    background: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/X5iq6dZ.jpg");
}
header {
    background:
url(https://raw.github.com/mmoustafa/Chalkboard/master/img/bg.png);
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Londrina Sketch', cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
header nav {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 80%;
}
header nav a {
    font-family: 'Ranga', cursive;
    text-decoration: overline;
    margin-right: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
header nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}
#section1 span {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white
}
#section1 span h1, #section1 span h2 {
  background: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/X5iq6dZ.jpg) -115px -95px no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Nathaniel Santley | Welcome to my site!</title>
    <link href="NathanielSantley.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Hi!  My name is Nathaniel Santley.  I'm a programming enthusiast, video game lover, and a nerd down to the core.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="nathaniel, santley, Nathaniel, Santley, programming, video, games">
    <meta name="author" content="Nathaniel Santley">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Nathaniel Santley</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Me</a>
            <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="section1">
        <span><h1>NATHANIEL SANTLEY</h1><br /><h2>Programming enthusiast.<br />Video game lover.<br />Nerd down to the core.</h2></span>
    </section>
    <section>

    </section>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

BTW: I got this from here: https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: Thank you so much dude!  I tried to search the web for it, but I didn't know how to word my problem in the search box.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this mental picture?

Comment: I have letter shapes cut out of a piece of paper the size of the span I have on my site.

Comment: I also have a picture the size of the background image.

Comment: Then I put the cut piece of paper on the background image.

Comment: Your example makes it as if i had the background image the same size as my paper and i put the cut piece of paper on *that* picture.

Comment: Could you make it so the site reflects that mental picture?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but whatever: The only way to do it is to use the same background *again* on those elements. I now moved that background to another position, but since there are two (adjacent) elements being affected, it's more complex than that. You can play around with the background positions yourself, and you can define two different rules for the `h1` and `h2`, using different (negative) background position values to place the background(s) exactly as desired. That way you can make it perfect.